# webpack4 js script execution order

Tags: webpack, chunks, iife, webpackjsonp

I'm playing around with a js project which uses webpack as bundler. i try to generate 3 files out of it (main, vendors and bootstrap). main contains the whole app, vendors are the npm packages and bootstrap contains advertising related code which has no dependencies to vendors nor main.

i do get the files generated but all of them are wrapped within the webpackJsonp construct and therefor not executable w/o runtime. the biggest pain point i am facing atm is, that my bootstrap.js gets downloaded along with the runtime and the vendors and main file but won't be executed till the largest file is downloaded as well (in my case the vendors).

**my question is**

do we have any option to tell webpack, that it should not wrap my bootstrap in the webpackJsonp construct but in an IIFE or at least tell it that it has no dep. and can be executed as soon as it is downloaded?

thanks a lot for all your hints and inputs.

Comment: Have you given https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputjsonpfunction a review? I'm unsure if this is helpful, but seems to be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to tell webpack to generate a single runtime chunk. It's size should be around 2kB. Would you consider this approach